# Bootstrap: Well is not aligned to form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `table` and a `form` one next to the other with Bootstrap. I have applied the `well` class to the `form`, to make it stand out. However, the `well` and the contained `form` are not aligned?

Please see my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/1161/).

How can I align the `well` and the `form`? (Notice that when both the `table` and `form` have the class `span6`, then all is good. However, I want `span7` and `span5` respectively.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `form` element's width is greater than the width defined by Bootstrap for `span5`, and thus some rendering engines will force the element to break out of the `well`.

If you absolutely have to use `span5`, try reducing the width of the labels, and margins of the `input` elements within the form.